# What class to select to remove URL underline?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to remove the underline from a URL on a hover event, but cannot figure out which class/CSS rule is affecting the div. At the bottom of the page is a "Related Posts" section, and when the cursor hovers over the image/article title, the title gets underlined.

The CSS rule I am applying to remove the underline is text-decoration:none

An example of the issue can be seen at the bottom of this page: http://50.87.248.154/~thetinat/healthy-personal-care-products-part-1/

I created CSS rules for many of the various cascading classes, such as: jp-relatedposts-post jp-relatedposts-post0 jp-relatedposts-post-thumbs

and even combined them all into one giant, super specific class, but still am unable to remove the underline.

tl;dr - What class selector do I need to use to target the Related Posts hyperlink in order to remove the underline that appears on a hover event?

Please let me know if I can clarify anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the significance of "***jp-relatedposts-post-a***" class. If you can add css to this class, then add the following:

```
.jp-relatedposts-post-a, .jp-relatedposts-post-a:hover{
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

If this doesnot works for you, then can you try:

```
a.jp-relatedposts-post-a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I added this to the stylesheet and it did not change the style

Comment: Donot override the link property from else where.

Comment: I dont know what rule is overriding it, otherwise I wouldn't be having this problem :D

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: may be you are overriding the css rule somewhere else. You can use text-decoration: none !important;. This will override any other css rules you have defined.

Comment: This works when the cursor is hovered over the title url, but it appears there is another rule acting upon the wrapper class that contains both the image and the title, because when the cursor hovers over the image, the underline appears. Any thoughts? (thanks for the help btw!)

Comment: I could be of more help if it is possible to see that in action.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div#jp-relatedposts div.jp-relatedposts-items div.jp-relatedposts-post:hover .jp-relatedposts-post-title a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

from jetpack.css.

[image: Debugger tools Inspector]

Use

```css
.jp-relatedposts-post-a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

***after*** jetpack.css or use `none !important;` if it’s impossible.

Comment: jetpack.css does not exist in the wordpress admin console. How can I edit that file? Is it automatically created through php?

Comment: @csterling I have no idea. I just posted what I saw. If you can’t edit it just use `!important`.